# Media Screen - Google Chrome Not Using Conditional CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use conditional CSS to render my page.  It appears as expected using Firefox, but not with Google Chrome.  It seems to be pulling the styles for the "@media all and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1920px )" section rather than the "@media screen and (min-width: 1920px)", even though the screen size is much wider than 1920px.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="hpBody">
    <div id="hpHeader"><div id="siteLogo"><img src='/images/logo.png' /></div></div>
    <div id="hpContainer">
        <div id="hpEvent">
            <div id="hpEventImage"><img src='/images/home_img.png' /></div>
            <div id="hpEventInfo"><h1 class="home_H1">My Title</h1><h2 class="home_H2">Subtitle</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div id="hpActions">
            <div id="hpEventBtn" class="btn"><img src='/images/inv.png' /></div>
            <div id="hpTenantBtn" class="btn"><img src='/images/inv.png' /></div>
            <div class='clear'></div>
            <div id="hpTourBtn" class="btn"><img src='/images/inv.png' /></div>
            <div id="hpAboutBtn" class="btn"><img src='/images/inv.png' /></div>
            <div class='clear'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my CSS is as follows:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Home*/
html, body { margin:0; padding:0;}
html { min-height:100%;position:relative }
body{ height:100%; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1em; color: #333333t; text-shadow:0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.1),0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1); }
div.clear { clear:both; }
img {height:auto; max-width:100%:}

#hpBody { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; overflow:hidden;z-index:-1; background:#fc0; }
    #hpHeader { background: url('/images/home_topbk_bar.png') repeat-x; width:100%; }
    #siteLogo { position:absolute; z-index:15;}
    #hpContainer { }

/* tablet landscape */
@media all and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1920px ) {
    #hpBody { background:red; }
        #hpHeader { min-height:210px; }
        #siteLogo { height:302px; width:846px; }
        #hpContainer { width:100%; }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    #hpBody { background:#ddd; }
    #hpHeader { height:15%; }
        #siteLogo { height:302px; width:846px; }
    #hpContainer { height:85%;}
}

    .home_H1{ font-size: 2.1em; font-weight: bold; }
    .home_H2{ font-size: 1.1em; }

/* CSS Events + Tour + About us + Tenants*/
H1, H2 { 
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow:0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.1),0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
    H1{ font-size: 2.3em; color: #000000f; }
    H2{ font-size: 1.7em; color: #7090c1;  margin-bottom:.5em; }
```